# Django allauth not able to login custom user, giving error asking to enter correct credentials--user exists in database

Tags: django, django-allauth

I having issues logging in a user with a custom user model with allauth. The user is in the database but is not able to login.

I am able to login as admin but not as other testusers I get an error asking to enter the correct username and password--the username and password are correct and the user is active.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, AbstractBaseUser



class UserModel(AbstractUser):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
            ('account_type_a','Account Type A'),
            ('account_type_b','Account Type B'),
            ('account_type_c','Account Type C'),
        )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    account_type = models.CharField(choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE, max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField( default=False)
```

I using the allauth login form like so:

**html**

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">Login</a>
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserModel'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [

    
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'memberships:profile'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'account_login'


ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False    # This removes the username field
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None
```